# How to return an array of all the dates between two selected dates using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

For my class assignment, I need to return an array of dates in between two selected dates on a calendar (arrival & departure).

I was given two sets of code that I can use, however I can't figure out how to link them together.

```
var arrival = document.getElementById('arrivalDate');
console.log(arrival.value);

var checkout = document.getElementById('departureDate');
console.log(checkout.value);

// Figure out the number of days they are check in for.
var days = checkout.value.split('-')[2] - arrival.value.split('-')[2];
console.log(days);

function dateRange(arrival, days) {
  range = [];

  // Starting At

  return range;
}
```

---

```
// Returns an array of dates between the two dates
var getDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
  var dates = [],
      currentDate = startDate,
      addDays = function(days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
      };
  while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    dates.push(currentDate);
    currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
  }
  return dates;
};

// Usage
var dates = getDates(new Date(2013,10,22), new Date(2013,11,25));                                                                                                           
dates.forEach(function(date) {
  console.log(date);
});
```

Comment: If `getDates` will give you all dates between a given range, all you have to do is generate a start date and an end date then call `getDates` with those two values. FYI, no one is going to do your homework for you so you need to show what you've done to try and solve it.

Comment: Do your homework! :X

Comment: thank you guys for your response :) i will do my hw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty simple when you've already been given the answer!

```
var arrivalDate = new Date(document.getElementById('arrivalDate').value);
var departureDate = new Date(document.getElementById('departureDate').value);
var dateRange = getDates(arrivalDate, departureDate);
```

Comment: Upvoted because it's your first answer and helpful, but would recommend not simply giving people homework answers :)

Comment: Also not good to suggest parsing of strings with the Date constructor, much better to use a library or small function or generate the Dates some other way.